# How to add a gap in gnuplot line?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot line plot. I'd like to add a gap (break) in the line to signify lack of data. How can I do that?

For example, let's say I have data between x=10->100, and also 200->500. So I want a line (the same line, so the legend matches) between 10 and 100, then a gap between 100 and 200, and again the line between 200 and 500.

I have tried adding empty datapoints (i.e. `-` y values), but gnuplot happily interpolates those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very subtle difference between:

```
plot 'data' u 1:2 w lines
```

and

```
plot 'data' u 1:($2) 2 lines
```

In your case, I think it should work to do:

```
set datafile missing '-'
plot 'data' u 1:($2) w lines
```

(**Note:** this results in a subtlely different plot than the blank line method I'll describe next).

Another way to do it is to just plot a blank line in the datafile where you want to have a gap.

e.g.:

```
#data
10 15
20 30
100 17

200 25
300 12
500 16
```

and then plot with either `plot 'data' u 1:2 w lines` or `plot 'data' u 1:($2) w lines`.  Both should produce an identical plot.

for more information, see `help missing` in gnuplot.

Comment: So what's the difference between `($2)` and `2`?

Comment: `$2` means take the information from the second column, just like `2` does.  However, you can do a lot of interesting things with the `$` notation.  You can do simple transformations on your data for example: `plot 'data' u 1:(3+$2)` (this adds 3 to all the data in the 2nd column before plotting).  It also behaves slightly differently w.r.t. missing data (apparently).  Possibly I should have put it first, but I really think the inserting of a blank record where you want to have line breaks is the best way to go here.  I just wanted to point out the use of `missing` data while I was at it.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense. I went with the `missing` notation because it's easier to fit into my analysis scripts.