# How to add a gap in gnuplot line when introducing a relative shift in x-axis?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file called `data_file.dat` which has two columns and 10 rows like this:

```
   #1   2
   1    2
   2    4
   3    6
   4    8
   5    16
   6    9
   7    7
   8    5
   9    3
   10   2
```

I am using `gnuplot` to plot the data points with a line and I have to produce a relative shift in the x-axis with the x value corresponding to the maximum y being at the origin. To do that, I use this:

```
    stats "data_file.dat" u 2 name "A"
    stats 'data_file.dat' using 1 every ::A_index_max::A_index_max nooutput
    A_pos_max_y = STATS_max
    plot 'data_file.dat' u ($1<A_pos_max_y ? $1+10-A_pos_max_y : $1-A_pos_max_y):2 w l
```

The output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bASlD.png). I need to remove the line which connects the y values at initial and final values of x. How do I make this 'gap' between those two points?

I checked this one solution [How to add a gap in gnuplot line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402076/how-to-add-a-gap-in-gnuplot-line) but because I don't have 'missing points' and my file is too large (way more than 10 rows) to do this manually, this is not helpful. Also, I am using stats to find maximum valued points, so I don't know where to produce the gap in my data file from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must plot the two parts separately:

```
stats "data_file.dat" u 2 name "A"
stats 'data_file.dat' using 1 every ::A_index_max::A_index_max nooutput
A_pos_max_y = STATS_max

set style data lines
plot 'data_file.dat' u ($1<A_pos_max_y ? $1+10-A_pos_max_y : 1/0):2 lt 1
    '' u ($1 >= A_pos_max_y ? $1-A_pos_max_y : 1/0):2 lt 1 t ''
```

The `1/0` results in invalid points which are silently skipped during plotting.